# How to show and hide div on the basis of radio button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two radio button on the selection of radio button it's should display div and hide div. Below is my script I don't understand why it's not working.

**JavaScript**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".text").show();
  $(".text1").hide();
  $("#r1").click(function() {
    $(".text").show();
    $(".text1").hide();
  });

  $("#r2").click(function() {
    $(".text1").show();
    $(".text").hide();
  });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<p>Show textboxes
  <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="r1" checked value="Show" onClick="getResults()">Do nothing
  <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="r2" onClick="getResults()" value="Show">
</p> Wonderful textboxes:
<div  class="text">
  <p>Textbox #1
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text" maxlength="30">
  </p>
  <p>Textbox #2
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text" maxlength="30">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="text1">
  <p>Textbox #3
    <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" maxlength="30">
  </p>
  <p>Textbox #4
    <input type="text" name="text2" id="text1" maxlength="30">
  </p>
</div>
```

[here is jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Ankurdev1/21dLv94k/)

Comment: Are you getting an error in the console? I get an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: getResults is not defined`. Doesn't look like that method is set up in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event handler to handle the change event and toggle the element state using [`toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method with a boolean argument.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // attach change event handler
  $("#r1,#r2").change(function() {
    // toggle based on the id
    $(".text").toggle(this.id == 'r1');
    $(".text1").toggle(this.id == 'r2');
    // trigger change event to hide initially
  }).first().change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Show textboxes
  <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="r1" checked value="Show">Do nothing
  <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="r2" value="Show">
</p> Wonderful textboxes:
<div class="text">
  <p>Textbox #1
    <input type="text" name="text" maxlength="30">
  </p>
  <p>Textbox #2
    <input type="text" name="text" maxlength="30">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="text1">
  <p>Textbox #3
    <input type="text" name="text1" maxlength="30">
  </p>
  <p>Textbox #4
    <input type="text" name="text2" maxlength="30">
  </p>
</div>
```

---

**FYI :** The attribute should be unique on the page, for a group of elements use class attribute otherwise only the first element with the id get selected while using id selector.

Comment: although this worked, but using same id's is not good practice at all. Please check in your code. you have to add a note about that and correct too (`id="text"` `id="text1"` is repeated)

Comment: @AlivetoDie :  it doesn't have any role here.... anyway I will add as note

Comment: i know that id play no role here. But i am just talking about convention.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is looking fine. make it sure that you add JQuery Properly

like

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".text").show();
  $(".text1").hide();
  $("#r1").click(function() {
    $(".text").show();
    $(".text1").hide();
  });

  $("#r2").click(function() {
    $(".text1").show();
    $(".text").hide();
  });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is working fine after added the jquery reference.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use toggle method for hide and show go to following link 
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp